# Why is modifying this String also modifying the content of another, seperate String?

Tags: c#, string, pointers, reference, compiler-optimization

In my static `main` function I have the following code:

```cs
string str1 = "aaaaaaaaa";
pointerTest();
Console.WriteLine( "str1 is: " + str1 );
```

The static `pointerTest`-method, which is declared as `unsafe`, contains the following:

```cs
string str2 = "aaaaaaaaa";
fixed( char* ptr = str2 )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < str2.Length / 3; ++i )
        ptr[i] = 'z';
}

Console.WriteLine( "str2 is: " + str2 );
```

Notice how `str1` and `str2` are independently declared, but do have the same content.

The **expected output** of this program would be:

```
str2 is: zzzaaaaaa
str1 is: aaaaaaaaa
```

When I run the program the **actual output** shows this:

```
str2 is: zzzaaaaaa
str1 is: zzzaaaaaa
```

**When I change `str2` or `str1` to not have the exact same content (for example by adding one more 'a' at the end of `str2`) the program acts like expected.**
If have found this behaviour to exist both in *.Net Core 3.1* and *Mono* (unsure about the exact version, I used [Repl.It](https://repl.it/))

**My question is why this behaviour happens and what can be done to get around it.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My theory is that this happens because of **compiler optimization**, specifically a process called **string interning**:

The compiler recognises that it would be unnecessary to allocate `str2` by itself, since there already is the exact same sequence of *chars* in memory, allocated with the initialization of `str1`. So instead of allocating it anew, it makes `str2` a reference to the location that `str1` is already pointing to. More about this can be read [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d551d3/what-is-string-interning/).

*Strings* are considered immutable in C#, so - under normal circumstances - it shouldn't be possible to modify their content in any way, shape or form.

Since this code is using the `unsafe` keyword and pointer-logic it is not guaranteed to not cause *undefined behaviour*, which leads to the sursprising result.

The only way to get around this "problem" is to adhere to the C#'s specifications and treat *Strings* as immutable.

Comment: This is called [string interning](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d551d3/what-is-string-interning/)

Comment: I did not know that, thank your for the input. I edited the answer to add the term and a link to the website you shared.